# Множественная вставка MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток, есть три таблицы MySQL:

1. Список фильмов Films(Id, title)
2. Список актеров People (id,name)
3. Актеры в фильмах people_in_film (film_id, person_id,character_name)

Через API сайта который предоставляет инфу по фильмам я получаю список актеров к этому фильму, на данный момент заполняю таблицу следующим образом

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO films (id, title) VALUES ($id, $title)");

$film_id = $db->lastid();
foreach ($peoples as $people){
   $db->query("INSERT INTO People (id, name) VALUES ('$people->id', '$people->name')");
   $people_id = $db->lastid();
   $db->query("INSERT INTO people_in_film (film_id, person_id,character_name) VALUES ('$film_id', '$people_id', '$person->character_name')");
}
```

Соответственно такой код нагружает MySQL ибо по 50 актеров обрабатывает и вставляет.....
Есть какой либо выход чтобы вставить те же данные за меньшее количество запросов к БД.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Скорее всего нет

Comment: @Алексей Дорохов, я вообще с трудом размещаю на весах подход, который вы показали. Объясню. У вас есть массив актеров, вы вносите их в таблицу "People", где они мирно списком и покоятся. Причем вносите их каждый раз и безапелляционно. То есть, если актер "*Алексей Дорохов*" у вас уже есть в таблице раз 100, то вы спокойно добавите его и 101-ый. Ну, и в чём прикол? Плюньте на эту таблицу вообще и заносите сразу всю когорту имён в таблицу "people_in_film". Да, я это с иронией, но поверьте, что при всей непродуманности проекта - это становится хорошим советом.

Answer (score 2):

Если у тебя серверачок с пентиумом 3-4, то тогда может и нагружает, тебе только кажется что нагружает БД, и много запросов, но на самом деле для того БД и создавалось, чтобы эффективно с ней работать и динамично. т.е. постоянный обмен данными.

Comment: Я на локали разрабатываю, и ищу методы оптимизации просто. 
Согласитесь, если есть способ сократить кол-во запросов, то почему бы им не воспользоваться

Answer (score 1):

```
bool mysqli::multi_query ( string $query );
```

[Читать про multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Answer (score 0):

Ну, можно попробовать несколько записей одновременно вставлять. С другой стороны, я делал парсинг кинопоиска и нагрузок не чувствовал и работало шустро. Плюс у меня была проверка на присутствие актера в базе, чтобы не добавлять его снова.